# JAX-RS Client - How to deserialize generic parameters from JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, json, rest, cxf

For purpose of code reusability I have a super interface and some more extending it such as:

```
public interface AbstractService<T extends AbstractDto> {
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces("application/json")
    T get(@QueryParam("id") Long id);
}

@WebService
@Path("/office")
public interface OfficeService extends AbstractService<OfficeDto> { }
```

And the client is:

```
OfficeService service = JAXRSClientFactory.create("http://...", OfficeService.class, 
    Arrays.asList(new Object[] {
        new org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider()
    }));
OfficeDto office = service.get(1L); // exception!
```

It fails with `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to OfficeDto`

If I remove the generics, everything is fine (except the code duplicates in all the services). It seems jackson does not understand that service's `T` is the actual `OfficeDto` and fails back to LinkedHashMap key-value pairs deserialization (which is fine for JavaScript, but is not for Java clients).

**How to use generic parameters in JAX-RS?** The current implementation is Apache CXF 3.1, but seems the same problem remains when switching to Jersey.